# Exchange 2007 - Exchange ActiveSync

Tags: exchange-2007, isa-server, activesync

We have ISA 2006 and Exchange 2007 and would like to get the Exchange ActiveSync to sync with non-windows base phones eg.Sony Ericsson...

We got it to sync with Windows base phone ie. smart phone or PDA... but not able to get it to syc with Sony Ericsson phone which is not a windows base phone.

Does anyone come across this issue before and how to solve it?

Comment: What is the model of the device that doesn't work?

Comment: Sony Ericsson C510

Comment: Need more info: what is the error when trying to sync, is it all non-WinMo phones or just that one (someone has an iPhone to test with) and make sure it's not user account specific.

Comment: Hi Ed,

I took the phone down to Telecom to test it with their network and the phone (Sony Ericsson C510) sync OK with their network.  I also try syncing with another Sony Ericsson mobile and get the same error (Session Failed).

PS.  My colleague has an iPhone and is syncing fine...

Comment: Just to add to my previous message, Nokia 6120 sync find on our network.  So this doesn't affect all non-windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

The device must support EAS, if not you will need 3rd party products, much the same way Blackberries work.

[HERE](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/support/phones/detailed/whatisexchangeactivesync?lc=en&cc=us) is a link with seemingly compatible Sony phones.

Comment: Hi Dan,

The device (Sony Ericsson C510) support EAS as I got Telecom to tested on their network and it sync OK.

Comment: You are able to connect other devices to your EAS?

Comment: Yes, i'm able to get iPhone, HTC SNAP and OKTA Touch phone to connect through Exchange ActiveSync.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly *is* the issue? "It doesn't work, has anyone come across this issue" covers a lot of ground. It just sits there not finding the EAS server? It finds it but can't connect? It connects but gives an error? It catches fire and you need to go buy a new phone? Something else? What?

Are there event log messages logged on the Exchange CAS when this phone connects? Are there any in the ISA server logs? Is the other place you've tested this at OK set up the same way as you with regards to ISA server publishing, etc?

Does the mobile phone support the type of certificate you're using? e.g. if you're using a "unified comms" certificate that allows you to protect several host names with subject alternative names, which is typical enough for a Exchange 2007 deployment, [will the phone support that type of certificate](https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name-compatibility.htm)? More basically than that, does the phone trust the certificate provider?

If you go into the account you're setting this up with in OWA, does the phone details page show anything? (OWA options / mobile devices)

What EAS policies are applied to the user? Are they compatible with what the phone itself can support? e.g. do you require info to be stored encrypted and the phone can't do that so won't sync due to that?